# Can't find data from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i wanna display my data fetch from mongo. but i could't get those data from DB.

```
app.get('/:filename', (req,res) => {
 var comments={}; 
 cmt.files.find({ image: req.params.filename}).toArray(function(err, 
  result) {
  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
  } else {
      comments = result
      console.log(comment);
  }
 });


});
```

This is my database(Image) and collection is comments

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure for request file name is same in db?

Comment: could plz check

Comment: then please check which data get from (req.params.filename). because your query is correct.

Comment: that is image name : 842eb3e8803484376bba0a0153435abe.jpg

Comment: this is my result : [ ]

Comment: email or skype me on janak@jksol.com